# Handling multiple XML files using XPath

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I want to insert multiple nodes values from multiple XML files into MySQL using `xpath` method. The code is as follows:

```
<?php 
$path="fs/";
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","sufi","1234"); 
if (!$con) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
mysql_select_db("test", $con);
if ( $handle = opendir($path) ) { 
     $files = array(); 
     while ( ($file = readdir($handle)) !== false ) { 
           $files[] = $file; 
     } 
     sort($files); 
     foreach ( $files as $file ) {
         $xml = simplexml_load_file("$file"); 
         $products[0] = (string)current($xml->xpath("/sioct:BoardPost/sioc:content"));
         $products[1] = (string)current($xml->xpath("/sioct:BoardPost/dcterms:created")); 
         $products[2] = (string)current($xml->xpath("/sioct:BoardPost/@rdfabout"));
         extract($products); 
         mysql_query("INSERT INTO forum (txt_content,txt_date,txt_about) 
                      VALUES ( '".mysql_escape_string($products[0])."',
                               '".mysql_escape_string($products[1])."',
                               '".mysql_escape_string($products[2])."')" ); 
     } 
} 
?>
```

But this gives me following error:

> Warning:  simplexml_load_file(.) [function.simplexml-load-file]:
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\readfiles.php
>   on line 22,  Warning: simplexml_load_file()
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external
>   entity "." in C:\wamp\www\readfiles.php on line 22, Fatal error: Call
>   to a member function xpath() on a non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\readfiles.php on line 23.

Kindly suggest some way to handle this.

Comment: Please take the time to format your code to make it readable.

Comment: I have tried with glob() to retrieve multiple xml files from a directory and I tried to insert contents of every file into mysql  but it does not insert any data to database, pls check my code and guide me:
'if ($handle = opendir($path)) {foreach(glob($path . "/*.xml") as $file) {$xml = simplexml_load_file($file); $products[0] = (string)current($xml->xpath("/sioct:BoardPost/sioc:content")); mysql_query("INSERT INTO forum (txt_content,txt_date,txt_about) VALUES ('".mysql_escape_string($products[0])."','".mysql_escape_string($products[1])."'‌​,'".mysql_escape_string($products[2])."')");}}'

Answer (score 0):

`readdir()` also returns "." and "..", this is what the error message tries to tell you there:

> Warning: simplexml_load_file(.) [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed
>   to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\readfiles.php on line
>   22, Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O
>   warning : **failed to load external entity "."** in
>   C:\wamp\www\readfiles.php on line 22, Fatal error: Call to a member
>   function xpath() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\readfiles.php on line
>   23

You could use `glob` instead:

```
foreach(glob($path . "/*.xml") as $file)
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I tried with glob() option but data did not populated in mysql and application also executed without error. if ($handle = opendir($path)) {$files = array();}while (($file = readdir($handle))!== false){$files[]=$file;foreach(glob($path . "/*.xml") as $file){$xml=simplexml_load_file("$files");  
$products[0] = (string)current($xml->xpath("/sioct:BoardPost/sioc:content")); mysql_query("INSERT INTO forum (txt_content,txt_date,txt_about)VALUES('".mysql_escape_string($products[0])."','".mysql_escape_string($products[1])."','".mysql_escape_string($products[2])."')"); }

Comment: I said glob **instead** readdir, not throw them together until nothing makes sense anymore... please look up, how [glob](http://php.net/glob) works.

Comment: Thank you, I tried with glob() but it again not insert any data to database, I think I am doing some basic mistake, kindly guide me to handle it: 'if ($handle = opendir($path)) 
{foreach(glob($path . "/*.xml") as $file)
{$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
$products[0] = (string)current($xml->xpath("/sioct:BoardPost/sioc:content")); 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO forum (txt_content,txt_date,txt_about) 
VALUES ('".mysql_escape_string($products[0])."','".mysql_escape_string($products[1])."','".mysql_escape_string($products[2])."')"); }
}